# Parsing json in Android - org.json.JSONException typeMismatch

Tags: android, json

I understand this question has been asked numerous times and I've looked at a lot of examples and questions with answers on this. Yet, even looking at what I think should be right, I am still getting the error from logcat of org.json.JSONException: Value of at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:100). There is some confusion on my part of how to go about extracting the info from the json or something in the json causing it to happen. Both of which I'm struggling to locate.

To start here is the full json

```
{
"data": "{\"haz\":[{\"id\":220121,\"rwn\":\"US-90 EAST\",\"dir\":0,\"cs\":\"MCCART ST\",\"lat\":29.777589,\"lon\":-95.284037,\"acc\":\"Minor Accident/Collision\",\"vi\":3,\"la\":\"Alternate Lanes\",\"mlb\":2,\"flb\":2,\"rlb\":0,\"hlb\":0,\"slb\":1,\"omb\":0,\"osb\":0,\"dc\":\"5/28/2014 4:34:41 AM\",\"dm\":\"12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM\",\"sum\":\"Right Shoulder, Right Lane, Center Lane\",\"toa\":0,\"toi\":0}],\"accident\":[{\"id\":220116,\"rwn\":\"IH-10 KATY\",\"dir\":0,\"cs\":\"WESTGREEN BLVD\",\"lat\":29.78518,\"lon\":-95.73529,\"acc\":\"Major Accident/Collision\",\"vi\":1,\"la\":\"Alternate Lanes\",\"mlb\":2,\"flb\":0,\"rlb\":0,\"hlb\":0,\"slb\":0,\"omb\":0,\"osb\":0,\"dc\":\"5/28/2014 3:40:24 AM\",\"dm\":\"12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM\",\"sum\":\"Left Lane, Center Lane\",\"toa\":2,\"toi\":1},{\"id\":220130,\"rwn\":\"IH-45 GULF\",\"dir\":4,\"cs\":\"SCARSDALE BLVD\",\"lat\":29.599,\"lon\":-95.1976,\"acc\":\"Minor Accident/Collision\",\"vi\":2,\"la\":\"Alternate Lanes\",\"mlb\":1,\"flb\":0,\"rlb\":0,\"hlb\":0,\"slb\":0,\"omb\":0,\"osb\":0,\"dc\":\"5/28/2014 6:11:32 AM\",\"dm\":\"12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM\",\"sum\":\"Center Lane\",\"toa\":1,\"toi\":1},{\"id\":220129,\"rwn\":\"IH-45 GULF\",\"dir\":4,\"cs\":\"SCARSDALE BLVD\",\"lat\":29.599,\"lon\":-95.1976,\"acc\":\"Minor Accident/Collision\",\"vi\":2,\"la\":\"Alternate Lanes\",\"mlb\":0,\"flb\":0,\"rlb\":0,\"hlb\":0,\"slb\":0,\"omb\":0,\"osb\":0,\"dc\":\"5/28/2014 6:06:19 AM\",\"dm\":\"12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM\",\"sum\":\"Unknown\",\"toa\":1,\"toi\":1},{\"id\":220127,\"rwn\":\"IH-45 NORTH\",\"dir\":4,\"cs\":\"N MAIN ST\",\"lat\":29.79018,\"lon\":-95.37202,\"acc\":\"Minor Accident/Collision\",\"vi\":2,\"la\":\"Alternate Lanes\",\"mlb\":1,\"flb\":0,\"rlb\":0,\"hlb\":0,\"slb\":0,\"omb\":0,\"osb\":0,\"dc\":\"5/28/2014 5:45:21 AM\",\"dm\":\"12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM\",\"sum\":\"Left Lane\",\"toa\":1,\"toi\":1},{\"id\":220131,\"rwn\":\"IH-610 SOUTH LOOP\",\"dir\":0,\"cs\":\"SH-225\",\"lat\":29.7096,\"lon\":-95.2674,\"acc\":\"Major Accident/Collision\",\"vi\":2,\"la\":\"Alternate Lanes\",\"mlb\":2,\"flb\":0,\"rlb\":0,\"hlb\":0,\"slb\":0,\"omb\":0,\"osb\":0,\"dc\":\"5/28/2014 6:18:55 AM\",\"dm\":\"12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM\",\"sum\":\"Right Lane, Center Lane\",\"toa\":1,\"toi\":1},{\"id\":220126,\"rwn\":\"SOUTH SAM HOUSTON TOLLWAY\",\"dir\":0,\"cs\":\"FUQUA\",\"lat\":29.60503,\"lon\":-95.47413,\"acc\":\"Major Accident/Collision\",\"vi\":2,\"la\":\"Alternate Lanes\",\"mlb\":1,\"flb\":0,\"rlb\":0,\"hlb\":0,\"slb\":1,\"omb\":0,\"osb\":0,\"dc\":\"5/28/2014 5:44:54 AM\",\"dm\":\"12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM\",\"sum\":\"Left Shoulder, Left Lane\",\"toa\":1,\"toi\":1}],\"highwater\":[{\"id\":220123,\"rwn\":\"IH-610 NORTH LOOP\",\"dir\":3,\"cs\":\"IH-45 NORTH\",\"lat\":29.8132,\"lon\":-95.3752,\"acc\":\"Minor Accident/Collision\",\"vi\":0,\"la\":\"Alternate Lanes\",\"mlb\":0,\"flb\":0,\"rlb\":1,\"hlb\":0,\"slb\":0,\"omb\":0,\"osb\":0,\"dc\":\"5/28/2014 4:53:25 AM\",\"dm\":\"12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM\",\"sum\":\"Exit Ramp\",\"toa\":0,\"toi\":2},{\"id\":220118,\"rwn\":\"US-290 NORTHWEST\",\"dir\":0,\"cs\":\"FM-529\",\"lat\":29.8795,\"lon\":-95.569,\"acc\":\"Minor Accident/Collision\",\"vi\":0,\"la\":\"Alternate Lanes\",\"mlb\":0,\"flb\":1,\"rlb\":0,\"hlb\":0,\"slb\":0,\"omb\":0,\"osb\":0,\"dc\":\"5/28/2014 4:12:17 AM\",\"dm\":\"12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM\",\"sum\":\"1 Frontage Road Lane\",\"toa\":0,\"toi\":2},{\"id\":220124,\"rwn\":\"US-90 ALTERNATE\",\"dir\":0,\"cs\":\"Lane Dr\",\"lat\":29.573644,\"lon\":-95.773905,\"acc\":\"Minor Accident/Collision\",\"vi\":0,\"la\":\"Alternate Lanes\",\"mlb\":0,\"flb\":0,\"rlb\":0,\"hlb\":0,\"slb\":0,\"omb\":0,\"osb\":0,\"dc\":\"5/28/2014 5:03:40 AM\",\"dm\":\"12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM\",\"sum\":\"Unknown\",\"toa\":0,\"toi\":2},{\"id\":220125,\"rwn\":\"US-90 ALTERNATE\",\"dir\":0,\"cs\":\"Chimney Rock Rd\",\"lat\":29.640602,\"lon\":-95.482381,\"acc\":\"Minor Accident/Collision\",\"vi\":0,\"la\":\"Alternate Lanes\",\"mlb\":0,\"flb\":0,\"rlb\":0,\"hlb\":0,\"slb\":0,\"omb\":0,\"osb\":0,\"dc\":\"5/28/2014 5:06:48 AM\",\"dm\":\"12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM\",\"sum\":\"Unknown\",\"toa\":0,\"toi\":2}],\"ice\":null,\"lostload\":[{\"id\":220122,\"rwn\":\"IH-10 EAST\",\"dir\":3,\"cs\":\"FREEPORT BLVD\",\"lat\":29.7707,\"lon\":-95.1778,\"acc\":\"Minor Accident/Collision\",\"vi\":0,\"la\":\"Alternate Lanes\",\"mlb\":0,\"flb\":2,\"rlb\":0,\"hlb\":0,\"slb\":0,\"omb\":0,\"osb\":0,\"dc\":\"5/28/2014 4:34:54 AM\",\"dm\":\"12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM\",\"sum\":\"2 Frontage Road Lanes\",\"toa\":0,\"toi\":4}],\"roaddebris\":[{\"id\":220117,\"rwn\":\"US-290 NORTHWEST\",\"dir\":3,\"cs\":\"FM-529\",\"lat\":29.8369039,\"lon\":-95.4991506,\"acc\":\"Minor Accident/Collision\",\"vi\":0,\"la\":\"Alternate Lanes\",\"mlb\":0,\"flb\":2,\"rlb\":0,\"hlb\":0,\"slb\":0,\"omb\":0,\"osb\":0,\"dc\":\"5/28/2014 4:11:35 AM\",\"dm\":\"12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM\",\"sum\":\"2 Frontage Road Lanes\",\"toa\":0,\"toi\":5}],\"stall\":[{\"id\":220128,\"rwn\":\"IH-45 NORTH\",\"dir\":4,\"cs\":\"N MAIN ST\",\"lat\":29.79018,\"lon\":-95.37202,\"acc\":\"Major Accident/Collision\",\"vi\":1,\"la\":\"Center Lane\",\"mlb\":1,\"flb\":0,\"rlb\":0,\"hlb\":0,\"slb\":0,\"omb\":0,\"osb\":0,\"dc\":\"5/28/2014 6:03:41 AM\",\"dm\":\"12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM\",\"sum\":\"Left Lane, Center Lane\",\"toa\":0,\"toi\":6},{\"id\":220129,\"rwn\":\"IH-45 GULF\",\"dir\":4,\"cs\":\"SCARSDALE BLVD\",\"lat\":29.599,\"lon\":-95.3586,\"acc\":\"Minor Accident/Collision\",\"vi\":2,\"la\":\"Alternate Lanes\",\"mlb\":0,\"flb\":0,\"rlb\":0,\"hlb\":0,\"slb\":0,\"omb\":0,\"osb\":0,\"dc\":\"5/28/2014 6:06:19 AM\",\"dm\":\"12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM\",\"sum\":\"Unknown\",\"toa\":0,\"toi\":6}],\"fire\":[{\"id\":220119,\"rwn\":\"BELTWAY 8-NORTH\",\"dir\":0,\"cs\":\"LEE RD\",\"lat\":29.9396,\"lon\":-95.3034,\"acc\":\"Minor Accident/Collision\",\"vi\":0,\"la\":\"Alternate Lanes\",\"mlb\":0,\"flb\":2,\"rlb\":0,\"hlb\":0,\"slb\":0,\"omb\":0,\"osb\":0,\"dc\":\"5/28/2014 4:22:56 AM\",\"dm\":\"12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM\",\"sum\":\"2 Frontage Road Lanes\",\"toa\":0,\"toi\":7}]}",
"error": 0,
"when": "6/6/2016 12:33:59 PM"}
```

For the parsing I attempt to do it like

```
JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(results);
JSONObject data = reader.getJSONObject("data");
```

I believe "data" is a JSONObject of reader and itself is filled with numerous JSONArray. This is where the error is thrown when attempting to read what I believe to be the JSONobject named "data"

Error (only snippet shown as its spitting out the entire json string)

```
org.json.JSONException: Value {"haz":[{"id":220121,"rwn":"US-90 EAST","dir":0,"cs":"MCCART ST","
at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:100)
```

Anyone see what I'm doing incorrect here?

Here is the full code I have for getting the info up to the error from the call back function

```
IncidentsList incidentsList = new IncidentsList();
JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(results);
        int error = reader.getInt("error");
        //there should always be a value for errors
        incidentsList.ERRORS = error == 1;

        //no errors, continue
        if(error == 0){
            Log.i("jsonreader", "no errors, read data object");
            JSONObject data = reader.getJSONObject("data");
            Log.i("jsonreader", "read data object");
        }
```

It never gets past the JSONObject data = reader.getJSONObject("data"); The logcat never shows the 2nd info statement

Thanks

Comment: The two lines of code you have posted is correct. Please post more code where you are trying to parse it.

Comment: Just noticed your json is invalid.

Comment: Please tell me more. I have full control of the json.

Comment: I recommend this site for future checks: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Please see my answer.

Comment: I took the full json, not the snippet I placed and ran it through the validator and it validated. Looks like I pasted incorrectly. If you'd like I can put the full json in if it'd help any.

Comment: Please put full json and the parsing code.

Comment: Replaced the snippet with the full json. The parsing code is already there. That is all I have so far.

Comment: The JSON you posted can't be full json. A json must end with `}` or `]`

Comment: My apologies. That got missed in the selection of it the json for copying and pasting. I've updated it. FYI.

Comment: I want to say your problem lays somewhere in the escaped quotes, which aren't needed unless you've directly copy pasted this is the Java code

Comment: @ClumsyHamster Updated my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I believe "data" is a JSONObject of reader

Nope, it's actually a string. Notice the quote before the brace.

```
"data": "{
```

If you have control over the JSON, I would encourage you to make it an object so it's both easier to read and parse.

Comment: Wow!. I didn't even see that and it full explains why things didn't get picked up. I'm going to have to look at redoing the json a bit different so they are objects. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: You could use getString and make a new JSONObject from that, but fixing the data source seems like the correct approach

Answer (score 0):

Your json string is invalid. It should end like

```
            "toi": 2
        }]
    },
    "errors": 0
}
```

but its ending like

```
            "toi": 2
        }], <------- this comma shouldn't be there
    },
    "errors": 0
}
```

**Update**

Error is `"data": "{\"haz\":`. It should be `"data": {\"haz\":`

and should end like

```
        },
    "error": 0,
    "when": "6/6/2016 12:33:59 PM"
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rohit5k2 but it was a pasting error. I've updated with the full json which validates.

Answer (score 0):

JSON format having extra comma "," as @Rohit5k2 said,
I suggest you to use GSON to easily parse your JSON,
instead of parse each element by jsonObject and jsonArray.

**your GSON model class can be**

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import java.util.List;

public class Resp {

    public DataEntity data;
    public int errors;

    public static Resp objectFromData(String str) {

        return new Gson().fromJson(str, Resp.class);
    }

    public static class DataEntity {
        public List<HazEntity> haz;
        public List<AccidentEntity> accident;
        public List<HighwaterEntity> highwater;

        public static DataEntity objectFromData(String str) {

            return new Gson().fromJson(str, DataEntity.class);
        }

        public static class HazEntity {
            public int id;
            public String rwn;
            public int dir;
            public String cs;
            public double lat;
            public double lon;
            public String acc;
            public int vi;
            public String la;
            public int mlb;
            public int flb;
            public int rlb;
            public int hlb;
            public int slb;
            public int omb;
            public int osb;
            public String dc;
            public String dm;
            public String sum;
            public int toa;
            public int toi;

            public static HazEntity objectFromData(String str) {

                return new Gson().fromJson(str, HazEntity.class);
            }
        }

        public static class AccidentEntity {
            public int id;
            public String rwn;
            public int dir;
            public String cs;
            public double lat;
            public double lon;
            public String acc;
            public int vi;
            public String la;
            public int mlb;
            public int flb;
            public int rlb;
            public int hlb;
            public int slb;
            public int omb;
            public int osb;
            public String dc;
            public String dm;
            public String sum;
            public int toa;
            public int toi;

            public static AccidentEntity objectFromData(String str) {

                return new Gson().fromJson(str, AccidentEntity.class);
            }
        }

        public static class HighwaterEntity {
            public int id;
            public String rwn;
            public int dir;
            public String cs;
            public double lat;
            public double lon;
            public String acc;
            public int vi;
            public String la;
            public int mlb;
            public int flb;
            public int rlb;
            public int hlb;
            public int slb;
            public int omb;
            public int osb;
            public String dc;
            public String dm;
            public String sum;
            public int toa;
            public int toi;

            public static HighwaterEntity objectFromData(String str) {

                return new Gson().fromJson(str, HighwaterEntity.class);
            }
        }
    }
}
```